# Como crear un textArea html5 que indique el numero de filas?

Tags: javascript, html5

[image]

Estoy comenzando con html5 y javascript y quisiera saber como colocar los numeros de fila en un textArea, así como se muestra en la imagen, también si puedo hacer lo mismo pero para las columnas. O si existe un componente especial para esto.

Answer (score 5):

Eso no se puede hacer con un elemento text area, siento decirte que hay mucho más código del que piensas en ese ejemplo. Para empezar, no sólo se puede escribir en un `input` o en un `textarea`, puedes escribir en cualquier elemento que admita el atributo [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable). Y para añadirle número de línea, tendrías que hacerlo a mano:

Aquí te pongo un pequeño ejemplo que no funciona del todo (como te digo, hay mucho trabajo detrás de un editor como el que quieres), pero te permite hacerte una idea.

```js
const editor=document.getElementById('editable');
editor.addEventListener('keydown',function(event) {
  
  if (event.code==='Enter'){
    var c = document.createElement('code');
    editor.appendChild(c);
    c.focus();
  }
});
```

```css
pre{
    counter-reset: line;
    
}
code{
    counter-increment: line;
    padding-left: 3px;
}



code:before{
    content: counter(line);
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<pre id="editable" contenteditable="true">
<code>Este texto en varias líneas</code>
<code>es editable</code>
</pre>
```

Mi recomendación es que si quieres un editor, uses alguna librería ya existente para añadirlo en tu web, como puede ser [Ace](https://ace.c9.io/) o [CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Lo que yo hice fue crear otro textArea al costado y que este no sea editable:

```
<textarea id="areaNumeracion" cols="1" rows="25" readonly></textarea>
<textarea id="txCodigo" cols="70" rows="25" onkeyup="numeracion(event);"></textarea>
```

y mediante JavaScript que se vaya agregando o quitando la numeración

```
window.onload = function () {
numeracion();}

function numeracion(e) {
let eArea = document.getElementById('areaNumeracion');
let eArea2 = document.getElementById('txCodigo');
let numeros = eArea2.value.split("\n").length;
let msj="";
for (let i = 0; i < numeros; i++) {
    msj += i + "\n";
}
eArea.value=msj;}
```

Y ya depende de ti si le das estilos

```
:root{
--color1:rgb(229, 223, 207);
--color2:rgb(251, 248, 241);
--color3:rgb(228, 71, 82);
--color4:rgb(5, 51, 84);
--color5:rgb(0,0,0);}

textarea {
resize: none;
text-align: end;
border: 0;
outline: none;}

#txCodigo{
text-align: start;
border-top: solid 2px var(--color5);
border-bottom: solid 2px var(--color5);
border-right: solid 2px var(--color5);
border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;}

#areaNumeracion{
margin: 0;
background: var(--color4);
color: var(--color1);
border: 0;
border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

este es un codigo para sacar la linea y la columna actual

```
var $textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');

function mostrarLineaYColumna(){
    console.log(insLinea());
    console.log(insColumna());
}


function insLinea(){
    return $textarea.value.substr(0, $textareaHtml.selectionStart).split("\n").length;
}

function insColumna(){
    var pos = $textarea.selectionStart; 
    var numChars = 0;
    var lineArr = $textarea.value.substr(0, pos).split("\n");
    for (var i = 0; i < lineArr.length - 1; i++)
        numChars += lineArr[i].length + 1;
    return pos - numChars;
}
```

primero cree una etiqueta textarea con una id 'textarea'

Answer (score -1):

**Aquí comparto un pequeño codigo,espero que te sirva.**

básicamente lo que hago es tener un div(.line) en el que guardaré
el numero de la linea, luego rompo el texto usando split("\n") para que devuelva un vector con cada liena

```js
function update(){
let line=1
let text=document.querySelector("#text").value
 document.querySelector(".line").innerHTML=" "
 text.split("\n").map(()=>{//aquí rompo el texto y recorro para ir añadiendo el numero
  document.querySelector(".line").innerHTML+="<p>"+line+"</p>"
  line++
})
}
window.onload=()=>{
  let editor=document.querySelector(".editor")
  let text=document.querySelector("#text")
  let line=document.querySelector(".line")
  //agrego un evento de scroll para mover ambos scroll al tiempo (el del editor y el del textarea)
    document.querySelector("#text").addEventListener("scroll",()=>{   
      let k=editor.scrollHeight/text.scrollHeight //usando proporción para mover simultáneamente ambos scrolls
      editor.scrollTop=text.scrollTop*k

    })
 
}
```

```css
*{
  --HEIGTH:200px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
main{
  height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: center;
}
.editor{
  background: #202121;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  height:var(--HEIGTH);
  overflow-y:auto;

}
.line{
  width:30px;
  padding-top:2px;
}
.line p {
    margin:2px 2px;
    background-color:white;
    color:"#202121";
    text-align: center;
    font-size:11px;
    padding-top:2px;
}
.text-cont{
  height:var(--HEIGTH);
}
#text{
  font-size: 15;
  padding:3px 0px 0px 1px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:9;
  height:var(--HEIGTH);
  resize:none;
}
#text:focus {
  outline:none;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="editor">
    <div class="line">
        <p>1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="text-cont">
      <textarea name="" id="text" 
             onkeyup="update()"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
</main>
```

Comment: Agrega el código _en la respuesta_, y explica qué hace. Recuerda que puede que el contenido del enlace que proporcionas ya no esté disponible más adelante, volviendo a la respuesta inválida. La respuesta no es solo para el OP (autor de la pregunta) sino para los demás usuarios de la comunidad. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Cuando tengas suficiente reputación podrás hacer comentarios a las respuestas, por mientras revisa [Como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: vale gracias por las sugerencias ;)